# How to solve an equation with matrices including vectors of ones

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following equation to solve:

$\mathbf{1}^T(-{Q_d}^{-1}(\lambda-b_d))=\mathbf{1}^T({Q_g}^{-1}\lambda)$

Here,$Q_d$ is a diagonal matrix with entries $q_{d1},q_{d2},\ldots,q_{dn}$.
$Q_g$ is similar, with entries $q_{g1},q_{g2},\ldots,q_{gn}$.
$\lambda$ and $b_d$ are both vectors with $n$ entries.
$\mathbf{1}^T$ is a vector of ones with $n$ entries.

Also, $\mathbf{\lambda}=\mathbf{1}^n*\lambda_*$ (so that every entry on $\lambda$ is the scalar $\lambda_*$ )

I would like to find $\lambda_*$. i can't figure out how to solve the equation. would these $\mathbf{1}^T$'s not be there i'd know how to do it. I can note use inverses because they are not inversivle. Also i can't just cancel them out like you would be able in a normal equation?

Answer (score 1):

Let's first remove the unnecessary bits: instead of $Q_d^{-1}$ and $Q_g^{-1}$, write $D$ and $E$ (diagonal matrices); instead of $b_d$ write $c$. Instead of $\lambda$ write $\alpha\mathbf{1}$, so the equation becomes
$$
\mathbf{1}^T(D(c-\alpha\mathbf{1}))=\mathbf{1}^T(E(\alpha\mathbf{1}))
$$
and you want to determine $\alpha$.

The equation can be rewritten
$$
\mathbf{1}^TDc-\alpha(\mathbf{1}^TD\mathbf{1})=
\alpha(\mathbf{1}^TE\mathbf{1})
$$
and therefore also
$$
\alpha(\mathbf{1}^T(D+E)\mathbf{1})=\mathbf{1}^TDc
$$
Note that, for a diagonal matrix $F=\operatorname{diag}(f_1,\dots,f_n)$,
$$
\mathbf{1}^TF\mathbf{1}=f_1+f_2+\dots+f_n
$$
Also $Dc$ has a nice expression in terms of the diagonal elements in $D$ and the coefficients of $c$. Just solve the simple equation and back substitute.